# My Brother.... not just a squabble

Tags: meaning

Hey my name's Jadon and I'm 14. I don't know if this is a good site to ask this question but I might as well LOL..

So basically my brother, who's 9, always thinks that everyone does stuff on purpose to him.  For example: He says pass that drink and I pass it to him but accidentally spill it over him. He would assume that I deliberately did that to him.

Thanks to anyone in advance I'm just wondering if there's a name for this?

Comment: "Paranoid" might be too strong a term. "Suspicious" or "untrusting" are other possible choices.

Comment: Conceited? Immature? Self centered? Or he might have a good reason to feel the way he does.